# ¿Cómo puedo colocar mi url en una peticion ajax si en la url tengo una variable que almacena el id de una fila de una base de datos?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Tengo un formulario que pienso hacer en ajax, mediante tres inputs tipo text y dos select dinamicos, un select se llenara cuando el usuario seleccione una familia
[image: Este es el formulario, cuando tenga los datos se agregaran a una tablita en formato json con js]

[image: Una vez que el usuario agregue un producto, se irá llenando la tablita y habrá un boton que será para guardar los datos json obtenidos, para mandarlos a mi base dedatos mysql]

El problema es que como estoy llenando el select que es para los productos con ajax, no sé como podría poner la ruta correctamente para que pueda hacerse la petición

este es mi código js

```js
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#filtrar_familia').on('change', function() {
                var familia_id = $(this).val();
                console.log("El id seleccionado es:" + familia_id);
                if ($.trim(familia_id) != '') {
                    $.get('obtener_productos', {
                        familia_id: familia_id
                    }, function(productos) {
                        var productoSelect = $('#productos_filtrados');
                        productoSelect.empty();
                        productoSelect.append(
                            "<option value='' selected disabled>Selecciona un producto</option>"
                        );

                        $.each(productos, function(index, value) {
                            productoSelect.append("<option value='" + index + "'>" + value +
                                "</option>");
                        });
                    }).fail(function() {
                        console.error('Error al obtener productos.');
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! a tu codigo le falta la llamada.. cual es tu duda en la llamada???